# Google Chrome - https security error on Google.com under Windows 7 Virtual Machine

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, virtual-machine, certificate, security-warning

I have Windows 7 32 Ultimate running under VMWare Player 6.0 on Windows 7 32 Host.

In Google Chrome v53 (and now also in latest v56), I am getting https security warning (‘Not Secure’) when accessing Google.com only when it’s accessed from within Virtual Machine and that too in Chrome.

This error does not occur on host Windows 7 and also not in Internet Explorer 8 even under VM. Other https sites are fine too.

My system date & timezone on both Host Windows 7 & Virtual Machine Windows 7 is correct.

Here’s a screenshot. I am not sure about the cause or reason for this error. Is there some certificate or encryption issue? How to resolve this?  Thanks.

I have ran Malwarebytes on Virtual Machine just to rule out any possible threats and its clean.

[image]

Certificate Snapshot on Host (No security error)
[image]

Certificate Snapshot on Guest in VM (security error)
[image]

Here’s the exported certificate received under VM in base64 format. To recreate the certificate, copy this text as-is into a blank notepad file (including BEGIN & END tags) and save it as .cer file.

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: Please provide the certificate as received by Chrome inside the VM.

Comment: Added the certificate snapshots.

Comment: No, well, please provide the actual certificate. :D You can export them on the “Details” tab.

Comment: Bizarrely, neither of those match the cert I get in my Win10 machine. Looks like Google is sending out different certs for its home page - no clear reason why - and one of them is still signed with SHA1 (that's the thing Chrome is objecting to, although the Google cert is see is signed with SHA256).

Comment: Your host is getting the wildcard *.google.com certificate and your guest is getting one for www.google.com; any security software installed?

Comment: I have Comodo Internet Security including Antivirus installed on Host and nothing on Guest in VM.

Comment: @Daniel B - the certificate as received under VM is added for reference.

Comment: Well I copied the certificate for *.google.com from the host into the virtual Windows 7 and installed it there. Now to my surprise accessing google.com picks up the installed certificate (I do not know if this is how it's supposed to work) and no longer gives me earlier security warning. Now it's valid https. While the issue is resolved, it's unclear why it occurred in the first place....what caused google.com to send/use a certificate with weaker SHA1 algorithm when accessed thru Chrome under Virtual Machine Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I went through some of the solutions suggested here:

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/zIYAENAJdVc

I installed chrome canary, which didn't have the same problem. And after that, my problem disappeared on regular chrome.